# UITableView - Adding additional rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have created a UITableView in an app, using the basis of a tutorial from the following link;

http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=353

I have customised the style to my needs and it works perfectly.  However, if i wanted to add additional rows to the table I come across a problem.  I have my three NSMutableArrays which contain category, subCategory and categoryDetails.  I have added an additional entry to each of the existing 6 to form a new row.

I assumed that would be ok, as the numberOfRowsInSection code is set to return [category count];

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [category count];
}
```

I assumed that by adding an entry for each array, adding an image it would check the category count and auto add a new row.  However, what it actually does it repeat the first array and then stack the new one on top of it overlapping.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there anywhere that you might have hard coded your array length of 6? Also, a picture might be very helpful for this problem if you can provide one, I'm having a hard time imaging what you mean by the arrays stacking/overlapping.

Comment: Hi, image can be seen here - http://d.pr/SESq - It creates the 7th row. so the category count is working. However, the labels seem to overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that its something to do with the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Without actually seeing the code i'd say that you are adding new labels pertaining to the 7th row to the already created 6th row. And hence the overlapping.

Comment: by the way as the other comment points out you gotta do [tableView reloadData]; whenever you change the contents of your data source, this tells the tableview that it needs to update the data. Are you doing that?

Comment: I dont get what you mean by changing the contents of the data source? Once the app is running, nothing is being changed or altered. The table contains a list of coded categories which don't change.

Comment: ok I see what you mean. So to reiterate you are saying that you actually have data for 7 rows but you can only see 6 rows? Plus have you added the data for 7th row in the viewdidload like the tutorial does? And can you please put an NSLog(@"rows : %d",[category count]); in the numberOfRowsInSection and see what number it shows up?

Comment: Yes, i have data for 7 rows. and 7 rows ARE showing up.  However, it seems that the UIlabel that are created, are overlapping for some reason. At first the 7th row has the UIlabel overlapped, but as you scroll up and down on the table the other labels start to overlap as well.  If only I could post a video

Comment: I also added  NSLog(@"rows : %d",[category count]); - however, it did not output anything to the console?? but I do have 7 rows showing up in my table.

Comment: yes i know exactly what you mean. that code is messed up. you see you are adding a new image everytime the cellForRowAtIndexPath is called. And it is called everytime you pull in a row from the top of the tableview or the bottom. Now that would have been fine if you were creating a new cell every time but what this code does is reuse the cells. That means that if there were 10 total rows and 6 were showing when you slide the 7th row from btm and the 1st row disappears, the 1st row is reused to show the data for the 7th row. So all the imageviews and labels for 7th row are added on the 1st cell

Comment: @imperiousdev let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2972/discussion-between-bizsytes-and-imperiousdev)

Comment: Ok, well that makes some sense to me.  However, when the app loads, the view initially shows 4 cells from my table. When I scroll down to cell 5 and 6 it works perfectly. It is in cell 7 where the issue arises. Why is that?  If i remove the data from the array for cell 7 everything works fine.  That is what I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the reload data method of the table view when your data changes?

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by 'when my data changes'?  The data is static, once I have entered my cells information it will remain exact.

Comment: you will need to post the method where you modify your arrays. This is where you will need to reload your data.